# Add an image to object in Unity editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

How do I add an image to an empty object? Which component should I add?

I've tried adding an "Image" component but I can't figure out what to do afterwards.

Comment: An `Image` must be located hierarchically inside a `Canvas` object.

Comment: Is the image you want to add a UI or a an image of a 2D object/character?

Comment: it's unlikely the OP knows the difference at this stage  :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Drag the image you want into the project directory and this will create a sprite from that image. Then drag that image onto the empty gameobject and it will create a sprite renderer component and will automatically add the image as the sprite for the sprite renderer. You can also do this manually by adding the sprite renderer and selecting your image as the sprite for the sprite renderer.

---

Note that if you are talking about ***Unity's UI system***, simply do this...

1. click "Add Canvas"
2. tip, be sure to select "Scale with screen size" there. (In 99.99999% of cases, you want that option.  It's bizarre Unity don't make it the default; just one of those whacky things about Unity.)
3. simply click "Add Image"

Add images like the crazy - it's that easy.  You'll have to learn to use Unity's (superb) reactive layout system to position stuff on the screen in an advanced way.  (Allow 3-4 months of study on that to become a hobbyist-level engineer on that system.)

Comment: For 2019.2.11, I had to follow steps 1 & 2 and then Add Component -> Image. If you just need a color, it has that ability instead of adding an image. Also, if you do want to add an image, it requires a Sprite - so on your imported image change it from "Default" to "Sprite" under Texture Type

Answer (score 7):

Create a raw image object using

```
Create -> UI -> Raw Image.
```

Then change the texture property as the png image.

Comment: To add an image to unity scene. The above method is enough. There is no need to insert an image. But the raw image should be in sprite 2d format

Answer (score 1):

You Should Try This Create>UI>Image and assign 2D Sprite

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the imported image Texture Type to Sprite (2D and UI). This can be changed in the inspector. The Default Texture Type did no allow me to attach to an empty GameObject.